# Vue.js - Package app as Figma Plugin using Vite

Tags: vue.js, figma, vite

I have a Vue.js app that I created with Vite. This app successfully runs when I use `npm run dev` and visit the app in the browser. Now, I'm trying to bundle the app as a single code file so that I can use it as a [plugin for Figma](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/libraries-and-bundling/).

I know that the `index.html` page loads because I can edit the HTML and see the changes. However, the page isn't loading/running the Vue.js app itself. I can see the following warning in the console log:

`<link rel=modulepreload> has no 'href' value`

My project is structured like this:

```
/
  /dist
    /assets
      index.a386f87b.css
      index.dc441194.js
      vendor.fbe8b50a.js
    index.html
    manifest.json
    plugin.js
  /src
    /views
      Index.vue
      Items.vue
      Calendar.vue
    /res
      /css
        theme.css
      /images
        loading.gif
        splash.jpeg
   App.vue
   main.js
   index.html
```

When I look at the index.html file in the `dist` directory, I see:

```html
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.dc441194.js"></script>
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/vendor.fbe8b50a.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.a386f87b.css">
<div id="app" class="position-absolute top-0 left-0 vh-100 vw-100"></div>
```

The references *look* correct. However, clearly something is wrong as the app is not loading as a plugin in Figma. Once again, I know I'm successfully loading the `index.html` file because if I manually edit it, the changes appear in the plugin. This leads me to [bundling the app as a single code file](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/libraries-and-bundling/). At this point, I'm stuck though. I don't see a way to accomplish this via Vite's built-in capabilities. I tried including the [`vite-plugin-singlefile` plugin](https://github.com/richardtallent/vite-plugin-singlefile). Unfortunately that didn't work for me either. Currently, my `vite.config.js` file looks like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig(({command, mode }) => {
  return {
    assetsDir: 'res',
    plugins: [
      vue(),
    ],
    root: 'src',
    build: {
      emptyOutDir: true,
      outDir: '../dist'
    }
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figma ignores `<script>.src` and `<link>.href`, which aligns with the docs you linked, stating *"all the code must be in one file"*.

Using [`vite-plugin-singlefile`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-singlefile) (as you mentioned) to inline all scripts and styles in `index.html` indeed seems to workaround the problem:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { viteSingleFile } from 'vite-plugin-singlefile'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), viteSingleFile()],
  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    assetsInlineLimit: 100000000,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: () => "everything.js",
      },
    },
  }
})
```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vite-vue-figma-plugin-demo)

[image: screenshot of Figma Vue plugin]